# Show the exact result of naive bayes for Text Classification in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, sklearn-pandas, naivebayes

I'm new in Machine Learning and Python. I want to classify some text in three groups. This Code from Github shows me just the statistics and prognosis. I want to see the exact classification. I mean, which text belongs to which group, for example in an excel file. I have no idea how to do it. Thanks for any help.

```
import sklearn.datasets as skd

categories = ['Dritte', 'EDT','EKN']
SAP_train = skd.load_files('C:/Users/s58916/PycharmProjects/textFiles/train/', categories= 
categories, encoding= 'ISO-8859-1')
SAP_test = skd.load_files('C:/Users/s58916/PycharmProjects/textFiles/test/', categories= 
categories, encoding= 'ISO-8859-1')

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB()) ])

# train the model
text_clf.fit(SAP_train.data, SAP_train.target)
# Predict the test cases
predicted = text_clf.predict(SAP_test.data)

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

print('Accuracy achieved is ' + str(np.mean(predicted == SAP_test.target)))
print(metrics.classification_report(SAP_test.target, predicted, 
target_names=SAP_test.target_names)),
metrics.confusion_matrix(SAP_test.target, predicted)
```

[image]

Comment: The `predicted` variable should hold the class predicted

Comment: Combine `SAP_test` with `predicted` to get the prediction for each text.